# The function should return 1 but it is returning 0

Tags: c++, function, reference

The following code takes input x and y and then calls a function. The function is supposed to be called 3 times in which case it will return 1. If, however, the values of x or y decline to very low levels the function won't be called 3 times in which case it will return 0.

My input is 3, 22. I can see that the value of t becomes 3 after the function has been called 3 times, but, it returns the value 0 instead of 1 (as seen from the value of i). Can someone explain why this is happening?

PS : Some sections of the code have been removed so that we can focus only on the relevant parts.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int turn_yeh(int &x, int &y)
{
    static int t = 0;

    cout << "t : " << t << " x: "<< x<< " y : " << y<<endl;

    if (t != 0 && t% 3 == 0) return 1;
    if(x!= 0 && t!= 2){x--; t++; turn_yeh(x,y);}
    else if(y >=10 && t!=2){y -= 10*t; turn_yeh(x,y);}
    if( y >= 2 && t == 2){y -= 2; t++; turn_yeh(x,y);}
    else return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;

    int i = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        i = turn_yeh(x ,y);
        cout << "i : " << i << endl;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            cout << "Hanako";
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior due to not returning in all code paths.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius is it undefined behaviour? Is there not an implicit return of default int value (0) when at the end of the function if no return is hit?
EDIT: You're absolutely right, the standard says `If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
the caller, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @Dillanm "_Is there not an implicit return of default int value (0)_" The only exception mentioned in the standard is the `main` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had written out your braces using one of the established conventions, you would have quickly discovered that there is not an explicit `return` value on all program control paths.

That means the behaviour of your code is *undefined*. (Note that `main` is an exception to this rule, with implicit `return 0;` statements added implicitly.)

You probably mean to write `return turn_yeh(x, y)` on the missing branches.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Comment: In this case, the return value ie. 1 will be returned to the calling function right? I want it to return the value directly to main. Can this be done?

Comment: @Primalr3d  Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. (This is recursion's best-kept secret.) You can't take a "shortcut" through several function calls in order to return a value.

Comment: If you want a variable to be set to 1 or 0, then pass that as a parameter by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your function probably needs to `return` the result of the recursive call:

```
int turn_yeh(int &x, int &y)
{
    static int t = 0;

    cout << "t : " << t << " x: "<< x<< " y : " << y<<endl;

    if (t != 0 && t% 3 == 0) return 1;
    if(x!= 0 && t!= 2){x--; t++; return turn_yeh(x,y);}
    else if(y >=10 && t!=2){y -= 10*t; return turn_yeh(x,y);}
    if( y >= 2 && t == 2){y -= 2; t++; return turn_yeh(x,y);}
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the returned value ie. 1 will be returned to the calling function right? I want it to return the value directly to main. Can this be done?